# why isn't lazy instantiation used in every getter

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the stanford course Paul Hegarty prefers to use lazy instantiation. For instance he makes a private declaration of

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) (NSArray *)cards
```

and then he uses the getter to perform an initialization

```
- (NSArray *) cards
{
   if(!_cards) _cards = [[NSArray alloc]init]
   return _cards;
}
```

I'm cool with that. What I don't get though is that at another time Paul declares a public suit for a playingCard being:

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *suit;
```

but in the implementation he doesn't perform this lazy instantiation. So I don't understand where the alloc init of the suit string happens? (suit being a pointer to an NSString - object which ought to get a place in the heap)

```
#import "PlayingCard.h"

@implementation PlayingCard
@synthesize suit = _suit;

- (void)setSuit:(NSString *)suit
{
    if ([@[@"♣︎", @"♠︎", @"♥︎", @"♦︎"]containsObject: suit]) {
        _suit = suit;
    }
}

- (NSString *)suit
{
    return _suit? _suit: @"?";
}
@end
```

Comment: To be honest one are that is wrong is constantly using the ivar directly other than instantiation. Should always use the setter (even if it is via self.propertyName syntactic sugar). Among other things, the setter helps keep KVO working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ask for the `cards` instance there is no additional information required (i.e. there are no necessary parameters). You just instantiate a `PlayingCard` and return it.

A `suit`, on the other hand, could be one of four options, so somebody needs to set that somewhere. Note that this issue is really independent of lazy initialization. It has more to do with the fact that `suit` expects to be initialized with a user-parameterized value.

Lazy initialization is a way to say, "*don't bother creating an instance of this object until I ask for it*." But in the case of `suit`, you don't want to create the string until the user supplies it.

Comment: Well I do understand the choice between a limited choices of values for the suit. But I thought it strange that no lazy instantiation was done. Agreed, the ? : in the getter resolves it by returning an @"?" and yeah if once does set it they will assign a pointer to a string object so I guess it's safe.

Comment: Why do you think that's strange? Lazy initialization is a way to say, "*don't bother creating an instance of this object until I ask for it*." But in the case of `suit`, you don't want to create the string until the user supplies it. How would you even go about lazily instantiating it?

Comment: I thought to put if(!_suit) _suit = [[NSString alloc]init] in the getter. This way I was sure that _suit would contain a pointer to a NSString-object. But I guess this object would be destroyed if someone did playingCard1.suit=@"5♠︎"

Answer (score 4):

The property is public, so he assumes that it will be set somewhere. When you set this property you can alloc, init and then set it to Playing card instance, for example:

```
PlayingCard *playingCard = [PlayingCard new];
[playingCard setSuit:@"spade"];
```

Lazy initialisation is used if property is private (so you can not initialise it outside of the class), but you don't want to initialise it in *init* method of the class.

Comment: I thought it strange that no lazy instantiation was done. Agreed, the ? : in the getter resolves it by returning an @"?" and yeah if once does set it they will assign a pointer to a string object so I guess it's safe.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy instantiation is not a panacea but can improve the object instantiation and app responsiveness if you don't spend cycles instantiating ivar objects all at once before you need them. This effect is nothing on a small simple class, but if you have a large set or array of objects, setting them all up completely at once will slow down things at one point.

To be fair the same hit could come later.